# Replacing DVD with an SSD in an HP Pavilion-dv6 laptop?

Tags: ssd, dvd, hp-pavilion

I have a laptop [HP Pavilion dv6-1149wm Entertainment PC](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02902404&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5141389), I'd like to replace the DVD writer, with an SSD, but I am wondering which adapter can fit, is this [CADDY Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0056EW4A4) relevant for this?

Comment: dumb but very relevant question - is the DVD drive removable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. It looks like you'll need a more specialized adapter/drive caddy in order for it to sit flush with the laptop's case. The one you link to may work but, if the outer plate of the OEM DVD drive isn't removable, it my not match the contours of the laptop case. It looks like the one below is made specifically for your computer.

http://www.qkyparts.com/hp-pavilion-dv6-1149wm-2nd-hdd-hard-drive-caddy.html